# quick question about definition of a divisor

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I know that if $f:C^{'} \rightarrow C$ is a holomorphic map beween complex riemann surfaces of positive genus, we can define the pull-back of a divisor $D \in $C$$. 
If i change the complex riemann surfaces with complex algebraic varieties with general dimensions is there a similar definition that extends the pull back of a divisor between riemann surfaces to complex algebrai varieties?

Comment: Yes, you can pull back divisors for general algebraic varieties.  Often, there one includes the requirement that the map $f$ does not take $C'$ into the support of the divisor (for reduced varieties).

Comment: where i can find this definition?

Comment: It's in the standard reference: Hartshorne.  You can also find a brief description at the beginning of Lazarsfeld's positivity book.  It depends on your experience with algebraic geometry.  You can also consider pull-backs of the invertible sheaf corresponding to the divisor.

Comment: It also makes a difference if you're working with a Cartier divisor or a Weil divisor.

Comment: i'm working with Weil divisor

Comment: Some details (but mostly for Cartier divisors) can be found here: [When do divisors pull back?](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/16888/when-do-divisors-pull-back)

Comment: @Michael. Your link is fantastic: thanks a lot.